# Fundamental Counting Principle

Tags: education, fundamental-solution

How many four-digit numbers can be formed from the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots , 10 \}$ if zero cannot be the first digit and the given conditions are to be satisfied

- Repetitions are allowed and the number must be even.
- Repetitions are allowed and the number must be divisible by $5$.
- The number must be odd and less than $4000$ with repetition allowed.

a. my solution is 2*10*10*10= 2000 because 2 is a even number and there are 10 numbers excluding 0 in set {0,1,2,3..10} and it is 4 digits that's why 2*10*10*10 
b.same in letter A but 2 is changed into 5 because it must be divisible by 5 so it is 5*10*10*10=5000 
c.same to A and B... Only I changed it to 3 so my solution is 3*10*10*10 = 3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9\cdot10\cdot10\cdot5=4500$:

- Digit #$1$ can be any of the $ 9$ digits in $[  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$2$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$3$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$4$ can be any of the $ 5$ digits in $[0,  2,  4,  6,  8  ]$

---

$9\cdot10\cdot10\cdot2=1800$:

- Digit #$1$ can be any of the $ 9$ digits in $[  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$2$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$3$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$4$ can be any of the $ 2$ digits in $[0,        5        ]$

---

$3\cdot10\cdot10\cdot5=1500$:

- Digit #$1$ can be any of the $ 3$ digits in $[  1,2,3            ]$
- Digit #$2$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$3$ can be any of the $10$ digits in $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$
- Digit #$4$ can be any of the $ 5$ digits in $[  1,  3,  5,  7,  9]$

Comment: Please explain how did you solved it and why?

Comment: @Jose: I'll make you a deal - if you add to your question a description of your attempts to solve this problem, then I will add to my answer a detailed description of the solution.

Comment: a. my solution is 2*10*10*10= 2000 because 2 is a even number  and there are 10 numbers excluding 0 in set {0,1,2,3..10} and it is 4 digits that's why 2*10*10*10
b.same in letter A but 2 is changed into 5 because it must be divisible by 5 so it is 5*10*10*10=5000
c.same to A and B... Only I changed it to 3 so my solution is 3*10*10*10 = 3000

Comment: I fell asleep yesterday because I'm tired studying..please help me

Comment: @Jose: Please add it in your question.

Comment: @Jose: You've got it so complete wrong, I don't even know where to start. For example, question a: "$2$ is an even number" - so what (on earth) has that got to do with the question??? It asks you how many even numbers are there. Even numbers are the ones **ending** with $0,2,4,6,8$!!! Also - "there are $10$ numbers excluding $0$ in set $\{0,1,2,3..10\}$" - since when is the number $10$ a digit?????

Comment: then where did u get 9 in 9x10x10x(2 or 5) ?

Comment: @Jose: See updated answer.

Comment: @Jose: And don't forget to accept it by clicking on the V next to it :)

Comment: Last question :) .. why 10 is not a digit in the set ?

Comment: @Jose: Because $10$ is not a digit, it is a number represented with **TWO** digits (on base $10$). The first digit of this number is $1$, and the second digit of this number is $0$.

Comment: Sir this is the last question ... in 3⋅10⋅10⋅5=1500 why digit #1 can be any of the 3 digits in [1,2,3] i mean why should it {1,2,3} like this ... why shouldt it will be like this Digit #1 can be any of the 9 digits in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]?

Comment: @Jose: The question says "less than $4000$". How can a $4$-digit number starting with a digit larger than $3$ can be less than $4000$???